# How can I submit jQuery form object (not ajax)?

Tags: jquery

How can I submit jQuery form object (not ajax)?

I try form.submit() and it doesn't work.

I create the form by

```
tempform = $("<form method='post'></form>");
tempform.attr("action", "abc.aspx");
```

and then append some form elements into it.

```
tempform.submit();
```

Comment: "Doesn't work" is a bit too vague. Help us to help you.

Comment: Your question reads, as you first submit the form and afterwards append some input fields. Did you meant what you wrote? Could you post a complete example to demonstrate the behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe try this:

```
tempform = $("<form method='post'></form>").attr('id','myForm');
tempform.attr("action", "abc.aspx");
$('body').append(tempform);
$('#myForm').submit();
```

Also worth pointing out that it has no elements. What makes you say it doesn't work?

Comment: Thanks. I forget to append the form to body.